# DBMS - Oracle | return multiple max values for multiple tables / relations

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I need to return a list of customers who had ordered maximum number items. I have added the following and get some results but need to filter the query to display multiple maximum values.

DDL

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(Cust_Num  NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
Cust_LName VARCHAR2(10),
Cust_FName VARCHAR2(10),
Cust_Address VARCHAR2(20),
Cust_City VARCHAR2(12),
Cust_State VARCHAR2(2),
Cust_Zip VARCHAR2(5),
Cust_Referred NUMBER(4));

Create Table BookOrder
(BO_OrderNum NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
BO_CustNum NUMBER(4) REFERENCES Customer(Cust_Num),
BO_OrderDate DATE,
BO_ShipDate DATE,
BO_ShipStreet VARCHAR2(18),
BO_ShipCity VARCHAR2(15),
BO_ShipState VARCHAR2(2),
BO_ShipZip VARCHAR2(5));

CREATE TABLE BookOrderItem
(BOI_OrderNum NUMBER(4) NOT NULL REFERENCES BookOrder(BO_OrderNum),
BOI_ItemNum NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
BOI_ISBN VARCHAR2(10) REFERENCES Book(Book_ISBN),
BOI_Qty NUMBER(3), 
CONSTRAINT bookorderitem_pk PRIMARY KEY (BOI_OrderNum, BOI_ItemNum));
```

I have written the following DML:

```
SELECT C.CUST_LNAME, C.CUST_FNAME, BO.BO_CUSTNUM, BOI.BOI_ORDERNUM, 
COUNT(BOI.BOI_ITEMNUM) AS Total_Items_Per_Order
FROM BookOrderItem BOI JOIN BookOrder BO ON BOI.BOI_OrderNum = BO.BO_OrderNum
JOIN Customer C ON C.Cust_Num = BO.BO_CustNum
GROUP BY C.Cust_LName, C.CUST_FName, BO.BO_CustNum, BOI.BOI_OrderNum
ORDER BY Total_Item_Per_Order DESC;
```

Which gives me the following results...

```
+------------+------------+------------+--------------+-----------------------+
| CUST_LNAME | CUST_FNAME | BO_CustNum | BOI_OrderNum | TOTAL_ITEMS_PER_ORDER |
+------------+------------+------------+--------------+-----------------------+
| NELSON     | BECCA      | 1017       | 1012         | 4                     |
| GIANA      | TAMMY      | 1007       | 1007         | 4                     |
| MORALES    | BONITA     | 1001       | 1003         | 3                     |
| MORALES    | BONITA     | 1001       | 1018         | 2                     |
| LUCAS      | JAKE       | 1010       | 1001         | 2                     |
| GIRARD     | CINDY      | 1005       | 1009         | 2                     |
| LEE        | JASMINE    | 1014       | 1013         | 1                     |
| MONTIASA   | GREG       | 1018       | 1005         | 1                     |
| MONTIASA   | GREG       | 1018       | 1019         | 1                     |
| PIERSON    | THOMAS     | 1004       | 1008         | 1                     |
| JONES      | KENNETH    | 1008       | 1020         | 1                     |
| MCGOVERN   | REESE      | 1011       | 1002         | 1                     |
| LUCAS      | JAKE       | 1010       | 1011         | 1                     |
| FALAH      | KENNETH    | 1020       | 1015         | 1                     |
| SMITH      | JENNIFER   | 1019       | 1010         | 1                     |
| GIRARD     | CINDY      | 1005       | 1000         | 1                     |
| SMITH      | LEILA      | 1003       | 1006         | 1                     |
| GIANA      | TAMMY      | 1007       | 1014         | 1                     |
| FALAH      | KENNETH    | 1020       | 1004         | 1                     |
| SMITH      | LEILA      | 1003       | 1016         | 1                     |
| SCHELL     | STEVE      | 1015       | 1017         | 1                     |
+------------+------------+------------+--------------+-----------------------+
```

As per this screenshot...

[image]

Comment: To improve the quality of your Question, please reproduce the output as formatted text within the Question rather than as a linked image.  This is because having to navigate to a linked image is a bit inconvenient and because links can break over time.  If you must include an image in your question, using `[][1]` will enable you to display it in your Question rather than as a link.  I have used `[]` here as you will not need to `enter an image description` but will still need the brackets.  If you have used more than one image, then please remember to change `1` to the number of the image.

Comment: Give some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Ideally it should return the row with the max amount of items per order number. If two order numbers have the same amount of items then both rows should be returned.

Comment: "max amount of items per order number"? When one order contains 2 x item A, 1 x item B and 4 x item C, this would be 4. Or are you simply looking for the "amount of items per order number", which would be 7 for this order?

Comment: Which version of Oracle? Do you simply want to show the first two rows of your results? In Oracle 12c you'd only have to add `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner , yes 12c. Thank you that worked like a charm. Was looking to return the maximum of items per ordernum, i.e if 4 items were counted as the maximum then return both. FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES did exactly that.

Comment: Great. I'll post this as an answer to help futuere readers with the same problem to find the solution quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT Cust_LName,
       Cust_FName,
       Cust_Num AS Cust_Num,
       BO_OrderNum AS Order_Num,
       BOI_ItemNum AS Item_Num,
       Max_Qty_Per_Order AS Max_Qty_Per_Order
FROM ( SELECT BOI_OrderNum AS Order_Num, 
              MAX( BOI_Qty ) AS Max_Qty_Per_Order
       FROM BookOrderItem
       GROUP BY BOI_OrderNum
     ) Max_Qty_Per_Order_Finder
JOIN BookOrderItem ON BookOrderItem.BOI_OrderNum = Max_Qty_Per_Order_Finder.Order_Num
                  AND BookOrderItem.BOI_Qty = Max_Qty_Per_Order_Finder.Max_Qty_Per_Order
JOIN BookOrder ON Max_Qty_Per_Order_Finder.Order_Num = BookOrder.BO_OrderNum
JOIN Customer Customer ON Customer.Cust_Num = BookOrder.BO_CustNum
ORDER BY Max_Qty_Per_Order DESC,
         BO_OrderNum,
         BOI_Item_Num;
```

This statement starts by creating a list of Order Numbers and the largest value of `BOI_Qty` associated with each.

The results of this subquery will be joined to `BookOrderItem` in such a way that only those records from `BookOrderItem` that have the largest value of `BOI_Qty` for their `BookOrder` will be returned.  If more than one `BookOrderItem` for a particular `BookOrder` has the maximum value of `BOI_Qty` for that `BookOrder`, then each such record will be retained.

The resulting dataset is then joined to `BookOrder` so that the value of `BO_CustNum` for that `BookOrder` may be retrieved and be used to join the dataset to `Customer`, allowing for the `Name` of a `Customer` associated with each `BookOrder` to be retrieved.

The desired fields for each record in our final dataset are then retrieved and sorted.

Please note that I have included the field `BOI_ItemNum` in the selected fields as you asked for each record that has the maximum value of `BOI_Qty` to be returned.  Without it such records would appear to be repeated.  Including `BOI_ItemNum` will allow you to identify each record returned.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

To only keep the first row(s) you'd use `FETCH FIRST n ROW(s) ONLY` in Oracle 12c. To consider ties, you'd replace `ONLY` by `WITH TIES`:

```
...
ORDER BY Total_Item_Per_Order DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES;
```